# Popup in Sidebar With Hosted Feature Layer, not ArcGIS Web Map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I see [this example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/popup_sidepanel.html) of how to put the contents of a popup into a sidebar, but I can't really follow it. I'm not sure how to implement it for my site, which uses feature layers hosted on ArcGIS Online, rather than a web map like the example.

It seems like the general idea is to turn off the popup, listen for selection changes, and then grab the infoWindow content and put it into a specified DIV. Am I right here?

How can I do this without using a web map?

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is an InfoTemplate on the FeatureLayer.

When configuring a pop-up for a layer in a WebMap, you get this "for free".

See an example of how to use InfoTemplate with a FeatureLayer

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/fl_popup.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you clarify the difference between popup template and info template? I've defined my popup template, but not info template.